# How to Wire Connector For Qualcomm 2.0 Battery

Tags: arduino

In my Arduino project I have a 12v motor which I would like to power using a Qualcomm external Battery. These Battery packs indicate that they supply 12v through a Usb type A cable around 2 amps. I want to solder a usb type B connector but not sure if that will work? I am new to this so I'm trying to find docs on how to wire this or if it even makes sense to do this?

Comment: Well, it if gives you 12V and you attach a USB peripheral to it (which is powered at 5V) if you are lucky you'll blow the fuse. If you aren't, you'll blow the board. So if it gives you 12V, DON'T attach a USB cable to it. Instead give that voltage to the Vin connector

Comment: The point you bring up is part of my confusion on this matter. I've read that the USB standard for ports is 5v. However, it would seem that Qualcomm is utilizing the USB connector but their port can send 12v through. The USB cable the Arduino Uno cable comes with says 30v on the cable which would seem to mean its not just for 5v. The Qualcomm info says it makes use of the d+ and d- of the usb cable so I'm not sure how that would work to wire this to a PCB board.

Comment: Wait, the USB standard tells that on the two outermost pins there should be 5V, while the two innermost pins carry the data (differential, from 0 to 3.3V if I remember correctly). Now, if a USB cable says it can withstand 30V means that the insulators can withstand that, not that the peripherals can. If you put 12V on the two data lines you will almost certainly fry the two protection components on the D+ and D- wires on the arduino board and, almost certainly too, also the USB-serial converter. The qualcomm USB connector is NOT a USB connector. It has the same shape but it's not.